# GetProcAddress returns 0 for the function name "RtlGetLastErrorString" in EasyHook32.dll?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

Opening the source code of EasyHook project, I can see that there are some DllImports importing the function `RtlGetLastErrorString` like this:

```
//DllName here is a const string equaling to "EasyHook32.dll"
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern String RtlGetLastErrorString();
```

So I assumed that function should exist. However the following code does not work expectedly (`GetProcAddress` returns 0):

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(String path);
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string path);

var mh = LoadLibrary("pathToEasyHook32.dll");
var procAddr = GetProcAddress(mh, "RtlGetLastErrorString");
```

`mh` is successfully returned. I've also tried different variant names: `RtlGetLastErrorStringA`, `RtlGetLastErrorStringW` but it's still the same.

`GetLastError` shows that the function name could not be found (error code: 127). So I believe it actual does not exist. But I wonder why the `DllImport` seems to find that function?

Is there any tool to view that function entry inside `EasyHook32.dll`? I've tried using `OllyDbg` but I'm not sure I used it well, I've tried viewing the `Executable modules` but they all look like the underlying modules loaded from Windows. I've tried finding all names in all modules and it seemed that there wasn't any entry named `RtlGetLastErrorString`. So looks like my understanding about DllImport has something wrong. At least the way DllImport obtains the function is different from the `GetProcAddress` does. It would be very nice if you could give me some explanation on this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the exported function name for dll.

The correct name for RtlGetLastErrorString is `_RtlGetLastErrorString@0`.

[image]

Comment: great! thank you very much. The tool is also very helpful, at least without such tool we hardly know exactly the function names to get.

Comment: @Hopeless: You don't really need a tool to get the decorated name for a symbol in C. You can easily construct it by reading [Format of a C decorated name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx#FormatC).

Comment: @lIInspectable thank you for that info, it is very helpful.